# Transform position of child object in Unity with own coordinates

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I hope the headline is not too confusing. At the moment I transform the position of a blank gameobject to use it for a LookAt rotation. The problem is, that I do something wrong with the child object. I will simply post pictures of the hierarchy.
[Hierachy of LookAt Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ihx.png)

I would like to transform the position with my coordinates of LookAtLeft and LookAtRight and let both shoulders look at it with LookAt. Sadly this does not work with my current script. Both LookAt objects are not on the same x and y position as my coordinates.

Here is my script I use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class SocketCLient : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    public GameObject lefthand;
    public GameObject righthand;
    public GameObject body;
    public float xPos = 10.0f;
    public float yPos = 10.0f;
    public float ryPos = 10.0f;
    public float rxPos = 10.00f;
    private float bxPos = 0;
    private float byPos = 0;
    private String newString;

    Thread receiveThread;
    UdpClient client;
    public int port;

    //info

    public string lastReceivedUDPPacket = "";
    public string allReceivedUDPPackets = "";

    void Start () {
        init();
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        Rect  rectObj=new Rect (40,10,200,400);

        GUIStyle  style  = new GUIStyle ();

        style .alignment  = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;

        GUI .Box (rectObj,"# UDPReceive\n127.0.0.1 "+port +" #\n"

                  //+ "shell> nc -u 127.0.0.1 : "+port +" \n"

                  + "\nLast Packet: \n"+ lastReceivedUDPPacket

                  // + "\n\nAll Messages: \n"+allReceivedUDPPackets

                  ,style );

    }

    private void init(){
        print ("UPDSend.init()");

        port = 5065;

        print ("Sending to 127.0.0.1 : " + port);

        receiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start ();

    }

    private void ReceiveData(){
        client = new UdpClient (port);
        while (true) {
            try{
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
                string[] separators = {",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", " "};
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                // print (">> " + text);
                lastReceivedUDPPacket=text;
                allReceivedUDPPackets=allReceivedUDPPackets+text;
                if (text.Contains("leftx")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    newString = text.Substring(5, 3);
                    xPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    print(xPos);
                }
                if (text.Contains("lefty")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    yPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    newString = text.Substring(5, 3);
                    // yPos = int.Parse(newString);
                    // print("yPos: ");
                    // print(yPos);
                    // if (yPos > 140)
                    //  yPos = -yPos;
                }
                if (text.Contains("bodyx")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    bxPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    newString = text.Substring(5, 3);
                    // bxPos = int.Parse(newString);
                }
                if (text.Contains("bodyy")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    byPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    newString = text.Substring(5, 3);
                    // byPos = int.Parse(newString);
                }
                if (text.Contains("righty")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    ryPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    newString = text.Substring(6, 3);
                    // ryPos = int.Parse(newString);
                }
                if (text.Contains("rightx")){
                    string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    rxPos = int.Parse(words[1]);
                    newString = text.Substring(6, 3);
                    // rxPos = int.Parse(newString);

                }
                //xPos = int.Parse(text);
                //xPos *= 0.021818f;
            }catch(Exception e){
                // print (e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public string getLatestUDPPacket(){
        allReceivedUDPPackets = "";
        return lastReceivedUDPPacket;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // print("xPos " + xPos.ToString());
        // print("rxPos " + rxPos.ToString());
        body.transform.position = new Vector3(bxPos, byPos);
        lefthand.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, -yPos);
        righthand.transform.position = new Vector3(-rxPos, -ryPos);
        print("rxPos: " + rxPos.ToString() + " ryPos: " + ryPos.ToString());
        // if(yPos < byPos)
        //  lefthand.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos , 0);
        // if(yPos > byPos)
        //  lefthand.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos , 0);  
        //lefthand.transform.Rotate(0, yPos,  -10, Space.World);
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit(){
        if (receiveThread != null) {
            receiveThread.Abort();
            Debug.Log(receiveThread.IsAlive); //must be false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `transform.localPosition`?

Comment: I tried that. It didnt work, maybe the wrong parent? Should be a higher object the parent?

Comment: Ah, I know what the problem is: you're trying to make an object look towards its own child. That will never work properly. Imagine trying to turn your whole body in order to look at your left shoulder. No, don't turn your head, turn your whole body. Guess what: you can never get there.

Comment: Yes thanks. It works better now, not satisfying, but better. Another problem is the thing with the axis. On the left shoulder the z axis looks up and on the right down. Is it really a solution to create an empty object an let the z axis look in the right direction and "put" the whole arm in this empty object?

Comment: Without knowing your exact setup, I can't say. Try it, see what happens, it might break something else. Alternatively you could just write some special-case code to handle the fact that it points the wrong way; I've got some `LookAt` code right now that uses `-1 * Camera.main.transform.up` (or similar) to point the right way.

Comment: How can I imagine that? You mean writing his own LookAt script?

Comment: What...? I meant *you personally* stand up and try to look at your shoulder. As a human.

Comment: No, I meant the `-1 * Camera.main.transform.up` thing

Comment: No, I mean using `transform.LookAt(pos, up)` and having to specify a negative direction (one that is actually down).